# How can I solve this javascript math problem?

Tags: javascript

I need help with this logic [problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxgm5.png) in Uri Online Judge site.

**The submitted code starts in "var a" and ends in the last `console.log`**, I used the var lines to work with an example of input

```js
var lines = ["3.0", "4.0", "5.2"];  
/**
 * Code your solution here
 */
var a = parseFloat(lines[0]); 
var b = parseFloat(lines[1]); 
var c = parseFloat(lines[2]); 
var areatr = (a * c) / 2; 
var areac = 3.14159 * (c * c); 
var areat = ((a + b) * c) / 2; 
var areaq = b * b; 
var arear = a * b; 

console.log("TRIANGULO: " + areatr.toFixed(3)); 
console.log("CIRCULO: " + areac.toFixed(3)); 
console.log("TRAPEZIO: " + areat.toFixed(3)); 
console.log("QUADRADO: " + areaq.toFixed(3)); 
console.log("RETANGULO: " + arear.toFixed(3));
```

when I submit my code, the console shows: Wrong answer (30%)
[image: code submitted]

Comment: It is not really a logic problem, but rather math problem. Just to make sure - you don't hardcode your input (`lines`) in your real submitted code, right?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post images as text inside the post body. If the link becomes inactive in the future, the question loses context and fails to be useful as a reference.

Comment: How you do you read input file? show us the code please. (I'm talking about the input file that "contains three double values with..".)

Comment: @VolodymyrBalytskyy this is meant to be the "var a", "var b", and "var c" variables

Comment: Try using `var lines = input.split(' ');` I think this will solve the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change how you process the input 
from: 
`var lines = input.split('\n');`

to:
`var lines = input.split(' ');`